# SQL XML XMLELEMENT - puuting more into root header

Tags: sql, xml, oracle11g, header, tags

I have created a XML SQL query and I'm finding it hard to find a solution in adding more in the header of the XML (see below). For every production record from the database table brought back there must be a parent header <**message**> tag and inside that message tag <**messageSequenceId**> there is a record  count (i.e. number, 1 for first production record, 2 for second production record and so on...).

The delivery tag <**delivery**> appears only once at the top and has a finish <**/delivery**> tag at the top too.

There is also an <**AV-XML**> which has a tag at the start and an end tag at the end of the output.

See an example of the output below. I just need these to finish the program off.

Thanks in advance for any replies I do get.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <AV-XML xmlns="http://www.iceservices.com/0.7/AV-XML" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.iceservices.com/0.7/AV-XML AV-XML.xsd">
 <delivery>  
    <supplierType>ADMIN-AGENCY</supplierType>   -- this is hard coded
    <supplierId>GEMA</supplierId>   -- this is hard coded
    <supplierName>Gesellschaft für musikalische Aufführungs- und mechanische</supplierName>   -- this is hard coded
    <supplierContactPerson>Jens Kindermann</supplierContactPerson>   -- this is hard coded
    <recieverContactPerson>n.n.</recieverContactPerson>  -- this is hard coded
    <format>AV-XML</format>   -- this is hard coded
    <versionId>0.7</versionId>    -- this is hard coded
    <creationDateTime>2016-03-09T12:24:46+01:00</creationDateTime> 
    <deliveryNo>201603091224460100</deliveryNo> 
    <otherInformation>MIGRATION FIRST DELIVERY</otherInformation>    -- this is hard coded
</delivery>
<message>  -- a message tag for each production record
    <messageSequenceId>1</messageSequenceId>
    <messageType>NEW</messageType>        -- this is hard coded
    <otherInformation>MIGRATION FIRST DELIVERY</otherInformation>  -- this is hard coded
    <production>
          production XML records information that I have already done in my query----------
     <production>
</message>
</AV-XML>
```

The SQL Query is below, the version of the database is 11g Release 1.

```
  select XMLROOT(    
           xmlagg(XMLElement("Production"  -- start level 1 tag for production
                                 ,XMLElement("prodCategoryType",prod.production_type)  
                                 ,XMLElement("prodStatusType",prod.dn_prst_status )  
                                 ,XMLElement("prodActive",'true')  
                                 ,XMLElement("prodCueStatusType",decode(prod.music_content_indicator,'Y','YES','NO')) 
                                 ,(select        XMLAGG(XMLElement("Cue"  -- start level 2 tag cue
                                                               ,XMLElement("cueId", rownum)
                                                                ,XMLElement("cueStatusType", cc.dn_ccst_status) 
                                                                ,XMLElement("cueCupType", 'NULL')
                                                                 ,XMLElement("cueType", 'NULL')
                                                                 ,XMLElement("cueOriginType", cc.gc_origin_of_cue_code) 
                                                                  ) 
                                                         )    -- end level 2 tag cue
                                    from prblk.creation_components cc  
                                    where cc.prod_cre_surr_id = prod.cre_surr_id
                                  ) ,
                                    XMLElement("endofproduction", prod.production_source) 
                              )  -- end level 1 tag for production
                  )  -- xmllag for production                                 
         , version '1.0'
         ) --  XMLROOT
  AS XMLRESULT   
  FROM prblk.productions prod 
  where prod.cre_surr_id in (1753959927,1753959929)
```

and the current output is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <Production>
  <prodCategoryType>EPI</prodCategoryType>
  <prodStatusType>5</prodStatusType>
  <prodActive>true</prodActive>
  <prodCueStatusType>YES</prodCueStatusType>
  <Cue>
     <cueId>1</cueId>
     <cueStatusType>2a</cueStatusType>
     <cueCupType>NULL</cueCupType>
     <cueType>NULL</cueType>
     <cueOriginType/>
   </Cue>
   <Cue>
     <cueId>2</cueId>
     <cueStatusType>2a</cueStatusType>
     <cueCupType>NULL</cueCupType>
     <cueType>NULL</cueType>
     <cueOriginType/>
   </Cue>
   <Cue>
     <cueId>3</cueId>
     <cueStatusType>2a</cueStatusType>
     <cueCupType>NULL</cueCupType>
     <cueType>NULL</cueType>
     <cueOriginType/>
   </Cue>
   <endofproduction>AP</endofproduction>
 </Production>
 <Production>
   <prodCategoryType>EPI</prodCategoryType>
   <prodStatusType>5</prodStatusType>
   <prodActive>true</prodActive>
   <prodCueStatusType>YES</prodCueStatusType>
   <Cue>
     <cueId>1</cueId>
     <cueStatusType>2a</cueStatusType>
     <cueCupType>NULL</cueCupType>
     <cueType>NULL</cueType>
     <cueOriginType/>
   </Cue>
   <Cue>
    <cueId>2</cueId>
    <cueStatusType>2a</cueStatusType>
    <cueCupType>NULL</cueCupType>
    <cueType>NULL</cueType>
    <cueOriginType/>
   </Cue>
   <endofproduction>AP</endofproduction>
</Production>
```

Comment: Is this data available in the moment you create the XML? Please show the query you are using at the moment and please show the XML exactly as it is coming out of your query.

Comment: and please specify your RDBMS (product and version) XML is **very** much depending on the actual software (SQL Server, Oracle, MySql...)

Comment: I've added the query, database version and the XML output from the query

Comment: OK, thx, I'm out, because I do not know Oracle well enough. But with your addition I'm sure that soon someone will answer...  Good luck!

Comment: Okay no problem Shnugo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `Message` is an outer element for `Production`, and the `messageSequenceId` is just the `rownum` for the main query - similar to the way you're getting `cueID` in the inner query.

So you can modify the query to to the XMLAgg on the message instead of the production; and then have a top-level AV-XML node which contains a new delivery element, and the messages aggregation.

```
SELECT XMLRoot(
  XMLElement("AV-XML"  -- start level 1 tag for AV-XML
    ,XMLAttributes('http://www.iceservices.com/0.7/AV-XML' as "xmlns"
      ,'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' as "xmlns:xs"
      ,'http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions' as "xmlns:fn"
      ,'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as "xmlns:xsi"
      ,'http://www.iceservices.com/0.7/AV-XML AV-XML.xsd' as "xsi:schemaLocation")
    ,XMLElement("Delivery"  -- -- start level 2 tag for delivery
      ,XMLElement("supplierType", 'ADMIN-AGENCY')
      ,XMLElement("supplierId", 'GEMA')
      ,XMLElement("supplierName"
        ,'Gesellschaft für musikalische Aufführungs- und mechanische')
      ,XMLElement("supplierContactPerson", 'Jens Kindermann')
      ,XMLElement("recieverContactPerson", 'n.n.')
      ,XMLElement("format", 'AV-XML')
      ,XMLElement("versionId", '0.7')
      ,XMLElement("creationDateTime"
        ,to_char(systimestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZHTZM'))
      ,XMLElement("deliveryNo"
        ,replace(to_char(systimestamp, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSTZHTZM'), '+', null))
      ,XMLElement("otherInformation", 'MIGRATION FIRST DELIVERY')
    )
    ,XMLAgg(  -- start XMLAgg for messages
      XMLElement("Message"  -- start level 2 tag for message
        ,XMLElement("messageSequenceId", rownum)
        ,XMLElement("messageType", 'NEW')
        ,XMLElement("otherInformation", 'MIGRATION FIRST DELIVERY')
        ,XMLElement("Production"  -- start level 3 tag for production
          ,XMLElement("prodId", rownum)
          ,XMLElement("prodCategoryType",prod.production_type)
          ,XMLElement("prodStatusType",prod.dn_prst_status )
          ,XMLElement("prodActive",'true')
          ,XMLElement("prodCueStatusType"
            ,decode(prod.music_content_indicator,'Y','YES','NO'))
          ,(
            SELECT XMLAgg(  -- start XMLAgg for cues
              XMLElement("Cue"  -- start level 4 tag for cue
                ,XMLElement("cueId", rownum)
                ,XMLElement("cueStatusType", cc.dn_ccst_status)
                ,XMLElement("cueCupType", 'NULL')
                ,XMLElement("cueType", 'NULL')
                ,XMLElement("cueOriginType", cc.gc_origin_of_cue_code)
              )  -- end level 4 tag cue
            )  -- end XMLAgg for cues
            FROM creation_components cc
            WHERE cc.prod_cre_surr_id = prod.cre_surr_id
          )
          ,XMLElement("endofproduction", prod.production_source)
        )  -- end level 3 tag for production
      )  -- end level 2 tag for message
    )  -- end XMLAgg for messages
  ) -- end AV-XML
  , version '1.0'
) --  XMLROOT
AS XMLRESULT
FROM productions prod
WHERE prod.cre_surr_id in (1753959927,1753959929);
```

You haven't said where `creationDateTime` and `deliveryNo` are coming from, so I've guessed they're both supposed to be the extraction time (from `systimestamp` to get the time zone offset), but you may have another way to generate those.

Comment: Amazing, it worked first time.... Alex Poole. You are a star, thank so much for your help.

Comment: @ShaunKinnair you could probably improve it further with XMLForest, joining the tables, maybe even dbms_xmlgen; and it looks like there ought to be a better way to generate the namespace info (or omit it, since none of the nodes use it). Glad it works for you though.

Comment: What do you mean when you say impoving with XMLForest and also joining the tables?, I'm new to SQL XML so don't know much about XMLForest.